# Is it fine to show every detail on dashboard for an admin panel or after one click?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

Well, I know the fact that we need to minimize the user click. But displaying too much information is also not good. So, as you can see from the image below, we have plans and a scrollable list of users who purchased the plan.

[image]

According to me, an admin will be more interested in looking at the number of plans that have been sold instead of who purchased the plan.

This seems like too much information for me.
What's your opinion?

- Should we continue with the only plans and how many plans were sold?
- Or should we also include list of users who purchased those plans to minimize extra clicks to see who purchased the plan?

Comment: Well, somebody came up with this design showing individual users. What was their rationale to show user names? I.e., what is the one or more use cases to be supported by this dashboard? Based on the goals to reach with this tool, you can determine what information is needed to support that goal. There is no "user names (don't) belong on a dashboard" rule...

Answer (score 0):

You're right. As a manager, I'm not interested in who bought the product, but the number of purchases and other helpful information (conversions, CTR, charts, etc.).

If I want to know something more specific, I look for it on a specific page or section where I expect to find information in tabular form (even if it could be expanded to a modal if I click).

However, if you need to do something like in your screenshot, you should at least try to make it as simple as possible and get rid of all decorative things like images, avatars, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You need a page to present all purchases, allowing filtering by plans. Also, consider including a "see more" link in your statistics, which would lead users to the "Purchases" page with the filter applied to the selected plan.

Comment: This isn't answering the actual question as to whether it's appropriate to show the level of detail at this stage or not. You're suggesting a totally different approach.